# Kion signifas silanverino?

Tags: word-meaning

(You're more than welcome to correct my grammar!)

Mi estas leganta libron en Esperanto (Libazar' kaj Tero) kaj mi ofte trovas la saman vorton: *silanverino*. Sed, mi ne povas konjekti nek ĝian signifon nek ĝiajn radikojn.

Mi suspektas, ke *silanverino* estas inventita vorto. Mi hieraŭ serĉis dum la tuta tago en la interreto kaj paperaj vortaroj... sed nenio aperis...

Bonvolu helpi min!

Comment: I think this article has the answer, but I'm too tired to parse it right now: Legu pri tio cxi tie: http://esperanto.net/literaturo/lg/libazarterrec.html Kaj bonvenon al StackExchange!

Comment: It occurs not a single time on http://tekstaro.com/, so I think it is indeed made up. --- Gxi ne aperas on http://tekstaro.com/, tiel mi pensas _silanverino_ estas vere inventita vorto.

Comment: Dankon! Mi ne volas legi tro multe (por eviti ĝojestingojn), sed mi povas kompreni, ke "silanverino" estas inventita vorto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via suspekto pravas. Laŭ la recenzo trovita de Charlotte SL, la difino estas

> ano de ina etno sur la for-fora planedo Libazar'. Tiuj Silanverinoj kapablas superi la neimageble grandajn distancojn en la sidera spaco, kaj virinforme aperi sur Tero. Ili havas ĉiujn ecojn de ideala edzino kaj de ideala homo.